# Oracle APEX - SQL - Creating a Sequential History and Calculating Days Between Each Phase

Tags: sql, oracle

So for one of my applications I have decided that I need the ability to capture more detailed metrics than I am currently doing. My group creates documents and specifically I want to know exactly how long (in days) that document has spent in each phase of its development. This data will be captured by an input form which will be filled out by a member of my team when they move a document to a different phase. The table for capturing this data is structured like so:

```
 TBL_DOC_TIMELINE
 DOC_ENTRY_ID     DOC_ID     DOC_STATUS     DOC_DATE       DOC_PHASE_DURATION
 1                123        Planned        06-05-2012
```

What I need to figure out how to do is when a new entry is created the `DOC_PHASE_DURATION` on the previous entry will be populated with the number of days between the `DOC_DATE` on the previous entry for that document and on the new one. It would look like this:

```
 DOC_ENTRY_ID     DOC_ID     DOC_STATUS     DOC_DATE       DOC_PHASE_DURATION
 1                123        Planned        06-05-2012     10     
 7                123        Draft          06-15-2012
```

All of our documents will be using the same table for this function so I cannot simply key on the DOC_ENTRY_ID though it can help. I will need to find the max DOC_ENTRY_ID for the DOC_ID and then calculate. I will need to do this until I reach the status of 'Published' and which point '0' should be inserted in the cell as that is the end of that DOC_ID's lifecycle. Like so:

```
 DOC_ENTRY_ID     DOC_ID     DOC_STATUS     DOC_DATE       DOC_PHASE_DURATION
 1                123        Planned        06-05-2012     10     
 7                123        Draft          06-15-2012     5
 38               123        Approval       06-20-2012     10 
 102              123        Published      06-30-2012     0
```

I would imagine that this would be in a SQL page process or even a trigger. Below is the psuedo-code I have pulled together but I am sure that its flawed. Have not had a chance to test it yet but I wanted to get your opinions on if I am on the right track. I will edit once I have had a chance to run it. Thanks.

```
UPDATE TBL_DOC_TIMELINE  
SET DOC_PHASE_DURATION = 
  (SELECT trunc((trunc(DOC_DATE)- &P1_DOC_DATE.)) 
  FROM TBL_DOC_TIMELINE WHERE &P1_DOC_ID. = DOC_ID) 
WHERE DOC_ENTRY_ID = 
  (SELECT MAX(DOC_ENTRY_ID) FROM TBL_DOC_TIMELINE WHERE &P1_DOC_ID. = DOC_ID);
```

Comment: Don't you know the `doc_entry_id` that you're updating at the time you're doing the update?

Comment: The DOC_ENTRY_ID that is being updated is the one that was previous to the one that was just submitted (So this process would only run on insert of the input form to add a new line). So in the 2nd example above you can see that when DOC_ENTRY_ID '2' is submitted that the DOC_PHASE_DURATION for DOC_ENTRY_ID '1' is what is updated. In reality this table will be used for all docs so the DOC_ENTRY_IDs may not be at all sequential. I just need to grab the previous most recent entry for that DOC_ID and update it.

Comment: Yes, and your code would do just that, however your sample data implies that the `doc_entry_id` you would need to update is the current - 1. It depends on whether you're using a compound key (doc_entry_id, doc_id) in order to enforce uniqueness or a surrogate key/.

Comment: I have changed the sequence of the DOC_ENTRY_ID in the example so that this confusion is no longer present. Basically what you are looking at is if I queried for one specific DOC_ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that you are already capturing all the metrics you need, since the duration can be **derived** from the existing data.  You could create a view:

```
create or replace  view vw_doc_timeline as
  select t.doc_entry_id, t.doc_id, t.doc_status, t.doc_date
       , case when doc_status = 'Published' then 0
              else lead(doc_date) over (partition by doc_id order by doc_entry_id)
                   - doc_date
              end as duration
  from tbl_doc_timeline t;
```

Then:

```
SQL> select * from vw_doc_timeline;

DOC_ENTRY_ID     DOC_ID DOC_STATUS                     DOC_DATE    DURATION
------------ ---------- ------------------------------ --------- ----------
           1        123 Planned                        05-JUN-12         10
           7        123 Draft                          15-JUN-12          5
          38        123 Approval                       20-JUN-12         10
         102        123 Published                      30-JUN-12          0
```

Comment: Tony, thanks for the help! It did indeed work great! I was wondering if you might also be able to help me figure out how to tweak this so that the last stage in the document's history (lets say the document is still in processing and has not been published) could be calculated against the sysdate() so that in the view there is never a null value. So in the example above DOC_ENTRY_ID '7' would have its date calculated against sysdate() until the next entry, DOC_ENTRY_ID '38', for that DOC_ID was entered and then DOC_ENTRY_ID '38' would calculate against sysdate. Thoughts? Thanks in advance!